# get lateset videos from some Youtube channels, using youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to build website (for my own) that show me 5 latest videos from 20 channels in youtube.
So I'm using for each specific channel in this following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API_KEY}&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=5
```

Each requst cost 100 unit, and for 20 channel is 2000 units, and I have just 10,000 units/day because the quota of youtube API. And because I trying to figure out how it works, and sometimes there are bugs too, I useing the same request many times, and my quota runs out fast.

So my quastion is: is there any way to replace the `SEARCH` request in, `CHANNEL`/`VIDEOS` (list) request to reduce the cost of the request (this cost is just 1 unit).
Or maybe to get in one request all the 5 videos from all the 20 channels?

Sorry for my English if there are any mistakes
Thanks in advance from everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may employ the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) API endpoint, queried with:

- `channelId=CHANNEL_ID`,
- `part=snippet,contentDetails`,
- `fields=items(snippet(type,publishedAt),contentDetails(upload))`, and
- `publishedAfter=...`.

where CHANNEL_ID varies among all the IDs of the channels of
your interest (thus `N` channels implying `N` endpoint calls).

You're supposed to compute a meaningful `publishedAfter` value to be passed to the endpoint. Attach such a value to each channel you're monitoring within your app, and maintain it to be *1 second plus the value of* [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.publishedAt) property corresponding to the newest video of that channel.

Initializing/resetting this per channel datetime value is done simply upon issuing an endpoint call without the `publishedAfter` parameter.

According to the docs, you'll get from this endpoint a result set made of [`Activities resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource) items that would contain the following info:

> [**contentDetails.upload**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.upload) (object)
> The upload object contains information about the uploaded video. This property is only present if the `snippet.type` is `upload`.
>
> [**contentDetails.upload.videoId**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.upload.videoId) (string)
> The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the uploaded video.

The official docs state that each call to `Activities.list` endpoint has a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of one unit.

Comment: thanks for your halp! it's fix my problem.
I didn't use the publishedAfter, it's return the 5 latest videos (maxResults).